# Optimize images in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, compression, image-compression

I am trying to reduce the imagesize of the webpage www.chevereganga.com by using this code in the htaccess-file. How does it work ?

```
<IFModule mod_deflate.c>
<filesmatch "\.(js|css|html|jpg|png|gif|jpeg|php)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</filesmatch>
</IFModule>
```

I got the following comments while running Google speedtest

Properly formatting and compressing images can save many bytes of data.
Optimize the following images to reduce their size by 10KiB (15% reduction).
Losslessly compressing http://www.chevereganga.com/img/gr%C3%B6nkartatrans.gif could save 3.7KiB (11% reduction).
Losslessly compressing http://www.chevereganga.com/img/landskap_splitblack.gif could save 2.6KiB (18% reduction).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. So what exactly is your questions? What is deflate algorithm? How to compress images? Feel free to edit your question to make it more precise.

Comment: I see now. The htaccess code was not fully rendered. I edited the question for you however in the future please make sure to format the code appropriately as it makes its easier to answer the question. SO uses a modified markdown syntax for questions and answers which allows you to highlight code, make text bold or italic, etc. You can find its help at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.